# Firebase Realtime Database: Uncaught TypeError: firebase.database is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to add firebase realtime database to my website, but when i use `firebase.database();` i get the following error:

> btncnt.js:44 Uncaught TypeError: firebase.database is not a function

This is my code:

```
    var Config = {
        apiKey: "********************",
        authDomain: "**********.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://*************",
        projectId: "***********",
        storageBucket: "**********",
        messagingSenderId: "**************",
        appId: "************"
    };
    // Initialize Firebase
    firebase.initializeApp(Config);
    console.log(firebase);
    var database = firebase.database();
```

Why is `firebase.database` not a function?

Comment: You have to include the firebase core `<script src="/__/firebase/6.3.4/firebase-app.js"></script>` and firebase database `<script src="/__/firebase/6.3.4/firebase-database.js"></script>`, if you want to you `firebase.database();`. You can also include the entire SDK like this: `<script src="/__/firebase/6.3.4/firebase.js"></script>`. See [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#libraries_hosting-urls) section by firebase.

Comment: @Minding That sounds like an answer to me. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to include the firebase core

```
<script src="/__/firebase/6.3.4/firebase-app.js"></script>
```

...and firebase database

```
<script src="/__/firebase/6.3.4/firebase-database.js"></script>
```

...if you want to use `firebase.database();`.

You can also include the entire SDK like this:

```
<script src="/__/firebase/6.3.4/firebase.js"></script>
```

See [this firebase article](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#libraries_hosting-urls) for more information.